# Overlay ggplots: error bars of same groupings but different data

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I overlay the following two plots, the first keeping colors defined as-is, and the second one providing reference line/errorbars in black. I don't have access to the raw data.

Edit: The black and colored error bars from the same c segment should have the same abscissa. The abscissa of different `c` segments should be offset by `position_dodge`.

I've tried geom_step(), then plot1 + plot2, which is closest to where I'd like to get, but there I loose the second plot's layout.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dta.str <- "G,C,P,y,ci
A,d,III,166.856088,34.719594
A,d,I,190.748296,37.181357
A,d,II,241.645888,47.168545
A,e,III,121.719736,28.456342
A,e,I,157.062248,36.273819
A,e,II,205.818768,48.619195
A,n,III,23.9916,8.624696
A,n,I,28.104488,7.401821
A,n,II,41.369656,10.522883
B,d,III,171.418816,14.739214
B,d,I,201.753368,16.673325
B,d,II,266.013168,21.616907
B,e,III,145.256352,10.781806
B,e,I,164.20732,11.317529
B,e,II,220.398488,15.320057
B,n,III,28.424464,3.211746
B,n,I,28.857352,3.106672
B,n,II,40.594432,4.191482"

dta <- read.csv( text=dta.str )

pd <- position_dodge(0.1) # if 0.1, move them .05 to the left and right

p <- ggplot( dta %>% filter( G == "A") , aes(x = P, y = y , colour = C )) + 
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-ci, ymax=y+ci), width=.1 , position=pd) +
      geom_line(position=pd,aes(group=C)) +
      geom_point(position=pd)

p <- p + ggplot( data = dta %>% filter( G == "B") , aes(x = P, y = y , colour = C  )) + 
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-ci, ymax=y+ci), width=.1 , position=pd) +
      geom_line(position=pd,aes(group=C) ) +
      geom_point(position=pd)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you just want this:

```
p <- ggplot( dta %>% filter( G == "A") , aes(x = P, y = y , colour = C, group = C )) + 
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-ci, ymax=y+ci), width=.1 , position=pd,color="black") +
        geom_line(position=pd,aes(group=C)) +
        geom_point(position=pd)
```

It seems you need to explicitly define `C` as your grouping variable for `position_dodge` to be applied consistently.

[image]

Comment: This seems to turn the red/green/blue errorbars of the first plot into black, not overlay the second plot to the first. I'm still not there, but it seems that in order to overlay plots, every "overlayed" geom needs to have its `data=` argument defined explicitly otherwise ggplot refers to the original data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a plot with the following:

- Points: to colour by variable `C` ("d", "e", "n") for both `G == "A"` and `G = "B"`;
- Lines: to group by variables `C` & `G`, and to colour by variable `C` for `G == "A"`, while keeping `colour == "black"` for `G == "B"`;
- Error bars: to colour by variable `C` for `G == "A"`, while keeping `colour = "black"` for `G == "B"`;
- Points, lines, & error bars at each value of `P` (on the x-axis), with the same `C` values, should be dodged to the same extent.

If that's the case, the main difficulty lies in defining two different colour palettes for points vs lines / error bars, when we only have one `scale_colour_XXX` to play with. I've adopted a workaround below, which relies on the fact that some shapes accept aesthetic mappings for both `fill` and `colour`:

```
# define fill / colour palette outside the ggplot object
n.colors = length(levels(dta$C))
fill.palette = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n.colors, "Set1") # change palette here
colour.palette = c(fill.palette, rep("black", n.colors))
names(fill.palette) <- levels(dta$C)
names(colour.palette) <- levels(interaction(dta$C, dta$G))

# plot
ggplot(dta,
       aes(x = P, y = y, fill = C, colour = interaction(C, G), group = C)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y-ci, ymax = y+ci), width = 0.1, position = pd) +
  geom_line(data = subset(dta, G == "A"), position = pd) +
  geom_line(data = subset(dta, G == "B"), position = pd) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, color = "white", size = 3, position = pd) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = fill.palette) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = colour.palette, guide = F)
```

A separate `geom_line()` is plotted for each value of `G` since we are only grouping by `C` (to maintain the same dodge position for different values of `G`).

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with. I'm sure there's a more elegant approach to this.

```
ggplot( data = dta %>% filter( G == "A" ) , 
        aes(x = P, y = y , colour = C , group = C )) + 
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-ci, ymax=y+ci), width=.1 , position=pd) +
      geom_line(position=pd,aes(group=C)) +
      geom_point(position=pd) +
geom_line( 
  data = dta %>% filter( G == "B" ) , 
  aes(x = P, y = y , colour = c, group = C), colour = "black" , position=pd ) +
geom_errorbar(
  data = dta %>% filter( G == "B" ),
  aes(ymin=y-ci, ymax=y+ci), width=.1 , position=pd, color="black") +
geom_point(
  data = dta %>% filter( G == "B" ) , 
  position=pd,color="black")
```